# How do I call a variable value stored in chrome.storage from a separate js file?

Tags: javascript, variables, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that does two different things depending on the option set by the user. How do I call the value stored in chrome storage

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
    var choice = document.getElementById('choices').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        selectedChoice: choice
    });
}
```

from a different js file? For example:

```
function loadOptions() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        theVariablePreviouslyStored
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to call the get method with the key you used to store the data, in this case `selectedChoice` and use a callback function to execute once the value is retrieved. Example:

```
function loadOptions() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['selectedChoice'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
}
```

More here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I have been looking everywhere; a lot of chrome documentation is 404s for some reason (maybe manifest v3)